# Can I compile .tex to .html from within AUCTeX?

Tags: compiling, emacs, auctex, html

Can I compile .tex to .html from within AUCTeX? What are the keybindings?

Thanks!

Comment: http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/auctex/11.86-extra/tex-ref.pdf

Comment: What are you using to compile to html? latex2html? I don't know what options are available...

Comment: @Seamus I am using htlatex, but I am not committed to it; it doesn't play nicely with files generated by pdflatex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can do it directly from `emacs` without having to use AUCTeX: `M-x compile` and then change the `Compile command:` to the appropriate `latex2html` command.  If you are going to be doing the .html rendering a lot, you can add the following code to the end of your .tex file:

```
% Local Variables:
% compile-command: "latex2html yourfile.tex"
```

From then on, whenever you load your .tex file the `M-x compile` command will default to the correct `latex2html` command.

You can bind `M-x compile` to a keyboard shortcut by adding something like `(global-set-key "\C-xc" 'compile)` to your .emacs file.

Comment: will this work alongside Auctex? Currently, it loads PDFLatex major mode when I open a .tex file.

Comment: I am fairly certain that it will not affect AUCTeX at all.

Comment: Also, you can obviously put whatever command you want (*e.g.*, `htlatex`) as the `compile-command`; it does not need to be `latex2html`.